# Netbeans Error for C++ Program Using Xercesc API

Tags: c++, netbeans

Hi all I'm trying to use the xercesc API for a program. I'm pretty sure I have correctly linked the API and included all the libraries because I can successfully run more than one sample program that xercesc provides. I'm using a Macbook Pro running OSX 10.10.1 and I have the newest version of Netbeans installed 8.0.1. This being said I get the following error message when trying to compile a slightly modified sample program:

```
g++    -c -g -Wall -I/opt/include -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU MacOSX/main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:63:10: fatal error: 'DOMTreeErrorReporter.hpp' file not found
#include "DOMTreeErrorReporter.hpp"
     ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is DOMTreeErrorReporter.hpp under /opt/include ?

Comment: I thought it was, but it seems after searching through the directories I can't find it. Is there an easy way to bypass reinstalling xercesc? For example I can find the correct DOMTreeReporter.hpp online very easily, therefore can I just create a header file and copy the contents into it, thus getting my program to compile and run?

Comment: I am not aware of it.

Comment: So to clarify the error message is essentially saying the program cannot compile because it cannot not find DOMTreeErrorReporter.hpp. Would this be a linker error? If so all I would have to do is link the directory where DOMTreeErrorReporter.hpp is located and my program should compile and run, correct?

Comment: this is compiler error. Find the path of the .hpp files and include the path in your command.

Comment: Ok I just realized that it was a compiler error. Thanks for your help